# what is apparmor "profile_replace" log message

Tags: apparmor

Can anyone explain this line in the log.smbd? Searching the internet for apparmor details gets so many hits I cannot find the information. This occurs when smbd is started.

```
kernel: [908896.070790] type=1400 audit(1442305563.416:371): apparmor="STATUS" 
  operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/nmbd"
  pid=16870 comm="apparmor_parser"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would beg to differ with Marks answer.

Any time I type `sudo service mysql restart` I see a similar message in syslog... time kernel:

```
audit: type=1400 apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/mysqld" pid=5014 comm="apparmor_parser"
```

If I then type `sudo aa-status` I see that mysql is in the list "nn processes are in enforce mode" 0 processes are in complain mode. 0 processes are unconfined but have a profile defined.

So I think this rather confusing message is just apparmor saying... I just found a process matching `profile="unconfined"` and I am going to perform `operation="profile_replace"`

These messages also appear when the pc is rebooted, presumably for the same reason, apparmor loads first, then as other processes load it confines them.

Answer (score 2):

It means the AppArmor profile affecting the program `/usr/sbin/nmbd` has been removed ("unconfined") using the `apparmor_parser` tool.  This means that program will run unrestricted by AppArmor from now on (until it's confined again - perhaps that will happen at boot, depending on how your system is set up).

If you're asking *why* it happens, I don't know.  Something is calling `apparmor_parser -R`, evidently, but why it would want to, or exactly how it gets called, I don't know.

Comment: can a profile be configured to set a program as running unconfined from the start, without having to execute a command to put it into that state?

Comment: Well, sort of. If you want the program to run unconfined, you need to find the profile (in `/etc/apparmor.d` - it MAY be called `usr.sbin.nmbd`) and either delete it or create a symlink to it from `/etc/apparmor.d/disable' - look in that folder for examples.  Reboot and check it behaves as you wish.